# C# ASP.NET MVC showing url parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a C# ASP.NET MVC application.  The application presents the user with a bootstrap styled login box.  When the user enters his/her user ID and password, that information is passed to the Mainpage controller.  The controller picks up the passed data and sends it to a custom build web service API.  The API validates the passed user ID and password and if the validation is passed, the API returns basic login information regarding the user.  The Mainpage controller takes that returned information, reformats it, and sends it along to a second custom web service API.  This second API takes the passed data, retrieves the participant information from a master database, and sends back a response.  The Mainpage controller then parses the response and populates a class and the class is passed to the view.  The view displays the data.  This all works as anticipated.

The question I have is in regard to the url that appears in the url box at the top of the browser.  When the View displays the webpage, the url that displays in the url box at the top of the browser contains the data elements that were passes to the custom API.  Here is a picture of the url box:

[image]

Obviously, I can not have user information showing in the url box.

How can I prevent the view from displaying this information?  I have no problem showing localhost:5001/MainPage (localhost: as this is currently in development) but I can not have the parameter fields and the data passed in those fields displaying.

Thanks.

EDIT #1:

The code in my Mainpage controller builds a url string and uses the following code to send the data to the API:

```
public MQ mq6000Send(string passedMQMessage)
{
    var mqResponseObject = new MQ();
    var localAPIReturn = new APIReturn();
    var url = "https://xxxxxxx-direct.com/api/homepage?mqRequest=" + passedMQMessage;

    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    var APIResponse = client.GetStringAsync(url).Result;
    APIResponse = APIResponse.Substring(1, APIResponse.Length - 2);
    APIReturn tempData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<APIReturn>(APIResponse);
    mqResponseObject.MQResponse = tempData;

    return mqResponseObject;
}
```

Comment: Make Your Action With Attribute  `[HttpPost]` And Format Your Form HTML to send post request not get **as get request displays data in url**

Comment: @MinaShenouda I am not submitting a form.  The code in my Mainpage controller builds a url string and uses GetStringAsync(url).  I will update my post with the code I am executing.

Comment: There's currently not enough technical background provided to help you. In particular, it's not clear how this information gets into the URl

Comment: @JonathanSmall You Mentioned **When the user enters his/her user ID and password, that information is passed to the Mainpage controller** so you send a request or what ?

Comment: @MinaShenouda - When the user enters his/her user ID and password, that is on a form with a generic submit button.  The application is C# ASP.NET MVC so the form data gets passed into the controller in the ActionResult (which does have the [HttpPost] attribute).  I validate the user id and password and if its valid, I execute a return RedirecToAction("Index", "MainPage", participantData).  This sends the participantData into the MainPage controller.  CRAP!!  The Mainpage controller ActionResult Index has no [HttpPost] attribute!  I bet thats it.  I'm going to retest.

Comment: @MinaShenouda Nope.  When I added the [HttpPost] attribute to the Mainpage controller ActionResult Index, I get a non-responsive page error.  Very strange.  I'm going to look further into this.  I think the [HttpPost] should be there.  Not sure why that causes an error.

Comment: @JonathanSmall you should have 2 actions which in your case name index one  is `[HttpPost]` and other  is `[HttpGet]`

Comment: Create chat room or screen your error I may help

Comment: @MinaShenouda - I dont know how to create a chat room, but I took a slightly different approach and took the data that I was passing to the second controller and placed it into TempData.  Now, my RedirectToAction just has ("Index", "MainPage") and I use JSON to serialize and deterialize the object and the data is passed and no longer appears in the url.  Thank You!